# Creating objects up to a point along a certain direction in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a horror game and part of that is a flashlight that an enemy can detect. I am using a set of cubes that the monster will be able to detect. I can't figure out how to create a line of those cubes from the flashlight to the wall.

I have grabbed the direction the torch is pointing in with:
`hitDirection = (hit.point - flashlight.transform.position).normalized;`

and the length of the ray cast by grabbing the hit distance (which I called "rayLength")
using that I created this for loop to create the object every metre:

```
for (int i = 0; i > rayLength; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(visionCube, new Vector3(), Quaternion.identity);
            }
```

Obviously the `new Vector3` is empty, this is because I have put a few things in there but nothing seems to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the normalized direction and mutliply it by the distance and add the origin.

```
for (float d = 0; d < rayLength; d += 1.0f)
{
    Instantiate(visionCube, originPosition + hitDirection * d, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This will create a cube at the origin, and every `1.0f` units away in the direction.  You may also want to create a final cube at the ray hit point, since it can be any distance between 0 and `increment` units from the last box you created.

If you want to change the distance each box is placed, change `d += 1.0f` to the distance you want.